# Left Outer Joins if condition not true

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am struggling a little bit with an SQL query. Too much time spent in Rails land lately!

I have three tables

```
Panels
id

BookingPanel (join table)
panel_id
booking_id

Booking
id
from_date
to_date
```

I want to select all the Panels that do not have a booking on a certain date. I tried the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "panels" 
LEFT JOIN "booking_panels" ON "booking_panels"."panel_id" = "panels"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "bookings" ON "bookings"."id" = "booking_panels"."booking_id" 
WHERE (bookings.from_date != '2015-04-11' AND bookings.to_date != '2015-04-16')
```

For some reason it doesn't return anything. If I change the dates where clause to = instead of != then it correctly find the records that are booked on that date. Why doesn't != find the opposite?

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails?

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: @Mischa I am using rails although I guess in this case its not particularly relevant. The code to product the above sql is Panel.joins('LEFT JOIN "booking_panels" ON "booking_panels"."panel_id" = "panels"."id"').joins('LEFT JOIN "bookings" ON "bookings"."id" = "booking_panels"."booking_id"').where("bookings.from_date != ? AND bookings.to_date != ?", "2015-04-11", "2015-04-16").count

Answer (score 1):

Applying the `WHERE` condition you do squashes your nice left joins into the equivalent of inner joins, on account of the fact that `NULL != <anything>` never evaluates to true.  This variation should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "panels" 
  LEFT JOIN "booking_panels"
    ON "booking_panels"."panel_id" = "panels"."id" 
  LEFT JOIN "bookings"
    ON "bookings"."id" = "booking_panels"."booking_id" 
    AND (bookings.from_date = '2015-04-11' OR bookings.to_date = '2015-04-16')
WHERE "bookings"."id" IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks John. NULL != <anything> never evals to true explains my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think about `not exists` for this purpose:

```
select count(*)
from panels p
where not exists (select 1
                  from booking_panes bp join
                       bookings b
                       on b.id = bp.booking_id
                  where bp.panel_id = p.id and
                        <date> >= b.from_date and
                        <date> < b.to_date + interval '1 day'
                 );
```

Note:  your question specifically is about one date.  However, the sample query has two dates, which is rather confusing.